# Selects checked values from check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I'm getting values to my html table using java script. Then i want to pass checked check box values back to my server. But the following script function always gives a 0 value selected array. My output is always same item for every check items.

```
function find() {

var dataObject = {};
var selected = [];
var i;

$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
    selected.push($(this).val());
    });

   for (var i = 0, len = selected.length; i < len; i++) {
    dataObject['id'+(i+1)] = (selected[i]);

 }
```

Comment: You probably don't have `value` attribute on your `input type='checkbox'` Also, what do you expect to get?

Comment: You may want to put a break point and check if `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` is empty or `selected` is empty.

Comment: show us your html. Also i think you may have some errors in your `for` you are using a comma instead of ";"

Answer (score 0):

not sure but try this one ;)

```
 function find() {

    var dataObject = {};
    var selected = [];
    var i;

    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (index, value) {
        selected.push(value);
        });

       for (var i = 0, len = selected.length; i < len; i++) {
        dataObject['id'+(i+1)] = (selected[i]);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

By selecting your checboxes with `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` you are already selecting only checkbox that are checked so the value is obviously checked.

A checkbox has two states: checked or not and the `checked` attribute reflects that not the `value` attribute.

you can however set the value attribute yourself to use it in post requests but you HAVE to set it first else the value of the `value` attribute of a checkbox is always 1.